# Angular and prime ng editor, add custome select in header

Tags: angular, primeng

In p-header i want to add new custom select and selected value need to insert in editor. Version of angular and primeng is 13
The editor is with formControlName

for example i have new select

```
<select class="custom">
    <option value="item-1">item-1</option>
    <option value="item-2">item-2</option>
</select>
```

and if select value to insert automaticaly here inside the editor

[image]

Comment: If you mean you want the selected option to be inserted into the editor, you could have the editor contents as a model, hook up a callback to the `select`, and then when the option is changed, you can just edit the model using the `select` callback.